# jquery plugin set value of this

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I am creating star rating box...
my php page is as below

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='alamStars.js'></script>
  <script>
    $().ready(function(){
       $("#txtStar").alamStar();
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
 if(isset($_GET[]))
 {
   echo $_GET['txtStar'];
 }
?>
 <form>
  <input type='text' name='txtStar' id='txtStar'>
  <input type='submit'>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my plugin code is as below

```
;(function ($) {
  $.fn.alamStar = function (options) {       
    var defaultVal = {
        img: '../images/start_rating.png',
        width: 105,
        height: 120
    }; //end array of default values

    var obj = $.extend(defaultVal, options);//overwrite default values if there
    this.after("<div id='alamStarBox' stars='"+this.val()+"'></div>");//dynamically create div
    var alamStarBox=$("#alamStarBox");//assign alamStarBox to a variable
    alamStarBox.html(this.val());//set initial value from textbox

    alamStarBox.css({
        'color'             :   'red',
        'background-image'  :   'url('+obj.img+')',
        'max-width'         :   obj.width+"px",
        'max-height'        :   obj.height+"px",
        'overflow'          :   'hidden'
    });//end styling css to alamStarBox

    alamStarBox.mousemove(function(e){
    var l=alamStarBox.offset().left;//Left value of alaStarBox
    var c=parseInt(e.pageX)+21;//current-position

    if(c>(parseInt(l)+parseInt(10)))
    {
        $(this).html("0");
        $(this).css('background-position-Y','0px');
    }
    if(c>(parseInt(l)+parseInt(30)))
    {
        $(this).html("1");
        $(this).css('background-position-Y','-20px');
    }
    if(c>(parseInt(l)+parseInt(50)))
    {
        $(this).html("2");
        $(this).css('background-position-Y','-40px');
    }
    if(c>(parseInt(l)+parseInt(70)))
    {
        $(this).html("3");
        $(this).css('background-positionY','-60px');
    }
    if(c>(parseInt(l)+parseInt(90)))
    {
        $(this).html("4");
        $(this).css('background-positionY','-80px');
    }
    if(c>(parseInt(l)+parseInt(110)))
    {
        $(this).html("5");
        $(this).css('background-positionY','-100px');
    }
});//end moue move function

alamStarBox.mouseout(function(){
    var p=parseInt($(this).attr("stars"))*20;
    $(this).css('background-positionY','-'+p+'px');
    $(this).html($(this).attr("stars"));
});//end function alamStarBox mouseOut

alamStarBox.click(function(){
    $(this).attr("stars",$(this).text());
});//end function alamStarBox click

var frm=this.closest("form");
frm.submit(function(){
    this.val(alamStarBox.text());//on submit form copy text from starbox to textBox
    //////////////////////////////////the above line is not working////////////////
});

 };//end alamStar function
})(jQuery);
```

I want to set textbox value equal to div text, in last function named frm.submit
but it is not working even assigning it static string like "static value"

Comment: Replace the `$().ready(function(){` with `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function() {`

Comment: where can I add return for chaining??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the copy of `this` in the parent function into another variable that you can then refer to in the callback function like this:

```
var self = this;
var frm = this.closest("form");
frm.submit(function(){
    self.val(alamStarBox.text());  //on submit form copy text from starbox to textBox
});
```

This happens because inside the submit callback function `this` will have a different value (most likely it will be the form DOM object).  Using a local variable named `self` or `that` or `me` is a very common design pattern for allowing a reference to the original object inside a local callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a callback on the jQuery `.submit` method of the form, so `this` is most likely not what you think it is (log it to console to see what it actually is).

Even `$(this)` will not work here, because that would be the form itself – and calling `.val()` on that makes no sense.

Select the input field explicitly in this function, then it should work: `$("#txtStar").val(…)`

Answer (score 0):

Either you use jfriend00's suggestion or you can use $.proxy() which change the scope of the submit hanlder to the original "this" value.

```
frm.submit($.proxy(function(){
    this.val(alamStarBox.text());   // NOW this=your textbox #txtStar
}, this));
```